# NextJS redirects not applied to client-side routing

Tags: next.js, url-routing, i18next, next.js13, next-router

I'm working on a NextJS project and trying to set up redirects and rewrites because I'm working with multiple locales. Redirects work correctly when entering URLs manually but do not work with internal links or "router.push" functions. I followed the documentation to resolve this issue, but it doesn't seem to work (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/redirects).

For example, I have a page: */en/about-us*

I have a rewrite for the French version of the page: */fr/qui-sommes-nous*. So when I request this url, the */about-us* page is displayed in the French version.

And I have redirects to handle internal language switchers:

*/fr/about-us* should be redirected to */fr/qui-sommes-nous*

*/en/qui-sommes-nous* should be redirected to */en/about-us*

And these redirects don't work on client side routing. I guess I'm missing something but I don't know what?

I'm using NextJS v.13.4.19.

I configured my redirects in *next.config.js* as follows:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    i18n: {
        locales: ['default', 'en', 'fr'],
        defaultLocale: 'default',
    },
    async rewrites() {
        return {
            beforeFiles: [
                {
                    source: '/fr/qui-sommes-nous',
                    destination: '/fr/about-us',
                    locale: false
                  }
            ]
        }
    },
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/fr/about-us',
                destination: '/fr/qui-sommes-nous',
                locale: false,
                permanent: true,
              },
              {
                source: '/en/qui-sommes-nous',
                destination: '/en/about-us',
                locale: false,
                permanent: true,
              }
        ]
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

The documentation says :

> Redirects are not applied to client-side routing (`Link`, `router.push`), unless [Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware) is present and matches the path.

So I also added a *middleware.js* file at the same level as my */pages* folder in the project:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/

export function middleware(req:NextRequest) {
  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next') ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/api/') ||
    PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname)
  ) {
    return
  }

  if (req.nextUrl.locale === 'default') {
    const locale = req.cookies.get('NEXT_LOCALE')?.value || 'fr'
 
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(`/${locale}${req.nextUrl.pathname}${req.nextUrl.search}`, req.url)
    )
  }
  
}


export const config = {
  /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
}
```

When I enter  */fr/about-us* in my browser, I am redirected to */fr/qui-sommes-nous* and everything works fine.

But then I am using <Link> to change the locale:

```
<Link href="/about-us" locale="fr">Button</Link>
```

And I am redirected to the French version of the page, but */fr/about-us* is still written in the url.

I am expecting the same result but with */fr/qui-sommes-nous* written in the address bar.

Thank you in advance if anyone can help me understand this problem,

Comment: What strategy are you using to change language of the page?

Comment: I use sub-path routing, then I use the locale prop on next/link to change locale.

Comment: For anyone passing by, after further research, configuring the project as I described above seems too complex or not possible, so I have decided to solve my problem by using only translated internal links (eg <Link href="/uber-uns" locale="de">link</Link> ) and make sure to never redirect to an incorrect link, or redirect towards home page "/" if needed to change locale while avoiding translation issues. It solves my problem for now, but I am still curious to know if, as the documentation suggests, there is a way to make rewrites and redirects work internally.